# Oracle SQL Developer to show multiple rows based on value at different column with same data

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I want to show multiple rows based on value for the example

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| Benedic | 3 |

this is on one table.

Expected

| Column A |
| --- |
| John |
| John |
| Benedic |
| Benedic |
| Benedic |

this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a row generator.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (cola, colb) as
  2    (select 'John'    , 2 from dual union all
  3     select 'Benedic' , 3 from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select cola
  6  from test cross join
  7    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                        connect by level <= colb
  9                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10  order by cola desc;

COLA
-------
John
John
Benedic
Benedic
Benedic

SQL>
```